# How to convert a certbot certificate private key to "Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA"?

Tags: tls, pem

I use `certbot` to generate ssl cert for my domain.

Then I use the following commands to copy the content to clipboard

```
cat ./letsencrypt/live/mycompany.com/cert.pem |pbcopy
cat ./letsencrypt/live/mycompany.com/privkey.pem |pbcopy
```

and paste into **Google App Engine**'s "Add a new SSL certificate" dialog box.

However the private key is rejected due to 'The private key you've selected does not appear to be valid.'

[image: I replaced the content with 'zzzz']

(I have replaced the content with 'zzzz')

How can I convert the certbot output into the right format?

Also I do not know exactly what format and roles are those certbot generated files are in.

```
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out I can use `openssl` to convert the format

> openssl rsa -in  ./letsencrypt/live/mycompany.com/privkey.pem  -out  ./letsencrypt/live/mycompany.com/privkey.pem.rsa.key

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@Anthony Kong](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/43483/anthony-kong)'s answer...

## What format are those certbot generated files in, and what roles do they perform?

The following are all PEM files [[info](https://serverfault.com/a/9717/433132)], which store the various different peices of information to allow the certificate to be used.

### Explanation

- **cert.pem**

  This is the issued certificate
- **chain.pem**

  This is the set of certificates that go from a trusted root down to the cert before the issued one
- **fullchain.pem**

  This is the set of certificates that go from a trusted root down to the issued one
- **privkey.pem**

  This is the private key for the issued certificate

### Examples

Imagine CA B is trusted by root A, and uses intermediate C to issue a certificate D.

The trust path would look like this

```
 A == Trusted root
\ /
 B == Issuing CA
\ /
 C == Intermediate Certificate
\ / 
 D == Issued certificate
```

In this case, the files would contain:

- **cert.pem**

  The certificate of D
- **chain.pem**

  The certificates of A,B,C
- **fullchain.pem**

  The certificates of A,B,C,D
- **privkey.pem**

  The private key of D